# Unable to Move Tabs between Two Tab Bars using Drag-and-Drop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tabs

I have two tab bars (tabBar and secondaryTabBar) in my web application. I'm trying to implement a feature that allows for moving tabs between these two tab bars using drag-and-drop. Currently, I can successfully move tabs from tabBar to secondaryTabBar, but moving them in the reverse direction (from secondaryTabBar to tabBar) doesn't work.

Here's the code related to the tab management and drag-and-drop functionality:

```
class Tab {
    constructor(name, contentClass, buttonClass) {
        this.name = name;
        this.contentClass = contentClass;
        this.buttonClass = buttonClass;
        this.buttonElement = this.createButton();
        this.contentElement = this.createContent();
    }
    createButton() {
        this.buttonElement = document.createElement('button');
        this.buttonElement.className = `tab-button ${this.buttonClass}`;
    
        this.buttonElement.setAttribute('draggable', true);
    
        this.buttonElement.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
            console.log(`Drag started for: ${this.name}`);
            e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', this.name);
            e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';

            // Using the button itself as the drag image
            e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(this.buttonElement, e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
        });
    
        this.buttonElement.addEventListener('dragover', (e) => {
            console.log(`Drag over: ${this.name}`);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    
        this.buttonElement.addEventListener('drop', (e) => {
            console.log(`Drop event on: ${this.name}`);
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            const tabName = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
            const tab = TabManager.findTabByName(tabName);
            if(tab) {
                TabManager.addDroppedTab(tab);
            }
        });
        
    
        // Close button creation
        const closeButton = document.createElement('span');
        closeButton.textContent = 'x';
        closeButton.className = 'close-tab';
        closeButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent tab activation when closing
            this.close();
        });
    
        // Append close button and tab name
        this.buttonElement.appendChild(closeButton);
        const tabNameElement = document.createElement('span');
        tabNameElement.textContent = this.name;
        this.buttonElement.appendChild(tabNameElement);
    
        this.buttonElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
            this.activate();
        });
    
        return this.buttonElement;
    }
    close() {
        // Remove the button from the tab bar
        this.buttonElement.remove();
        // Remove the content from the content div
        this.contentElement.remove();
        // Remove the tab instance from TabManager.tabs
        const tabIndex = TabManager.tabs.indexOf(this);
        if (tabIndex !== -1) {
            TabManager.tabs.splice(tabIndex, 1);
        }
    }
    createContent() {
        const content = document.createElement('div');
        content.className = `tab ${this.contentClass}`;
        return content;
    }
    activate() {
        const currentTabBar = this.buttonElement.parentElement;
    
        // Deactivate all tabs in the current tab-bar
        TabManager.deactivateTabsInBar(currentTabBar);
    
        this.buttonElement.classList.add('active');
        this.contentElement.classList.add('active');
    }
    deactivate() {
        this.buttonElement.classList.remove('active');
        this.contentElement.classList.remove('active');
    }
}

class TabManager {
    static tabs = [];
    static tabBarElement = null;
    static contentDiv = null;
    static secondaryTabBarElement = null;
    static secondaryContentDiv = null;

    static initialize(tabBar, contentDiv, secondaryTabBar, secondaryContentDiv) {
        this.tabBarElement = tabBar;
        this.contentDiv = contentDiv;
        this.secondaryTabBarElement = secondaryTabBar;
        this.secondaryContentDiv = secondaryContentDiv;

        // Add the dragover event listeners
        this.tabBarElement.addEventListener('dragover', this.handleDragOver);
        this.secondaryTabBarElement.addEventListener('dragover', this.handleDragOver);

        this.tabBarElement.addEventListener('drop', this.handleDrop);
        this.secondaryTabBarElement.addEventListener('drop', this.handleDrop);
    }

    static handleDrop(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
        console.log('Drop event on tab bar: ' + e.currentTarget.className);
        
        const tabName = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
        const tab = TabManager.findTabByName(tabName);
        if(tab) {
            TabManager.addDroppedTab(tab, e);
        }
    }

    static handleDragOver(e) {
        console.log('Drag over tab bar: ' + e.target.className);
        e.preventDefault();
        e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
    }

    static addDroppedTab(tab, e) {
        // Check which tab bar is closer to the drop point
        const primaryDist = Math.abs(this.tabBarElement.getBoundingClientRect().top - e.clientY);
        const secondaryDist = Math.abs(this.secondaryTabBarElement.getBoundingClientRect().top - e.clientY);

        const targetTabBar = primaryDist < secondaryDist ? this.tabBarElement : this.secondaryTabBarElement;
        const targetContentDiv = primaryDist < secondaryDist ? this.contentDiv : this.secondaryContentDiv;

        targetTabBar.appendChild(tab.buttonElement);
        targetContentDiv.appendChild(tab.contentElement);
        
        //activate the dropped tab
        tab.activate();
    }

    static findTabByName(name) {
        return this.tabs.find(tab => tab.name === name);
    }

    static addTab(tab) {
        if (!(tab instanceof Tab)) {
            console.error("Not a Tab instance");
            return;
        }

        if (this.tabs.indexOf(tab) !== -1) {
            console.warn("Tab is already added. Skipping...");
            return;
        }

        this.tabs.push(tab);

        // Add the tab to the tabBar with fewer tabs, or primary if they're equal
        if (this.tabBarElement.childElementCount <= this.secondaryTabBarElement.childElementCount) {
            this.tabBarElement.appendChild(tab.buttonElement);
            this.contentDiv.appendChild(tab.contentElement);
            if (!Array.from(this.tabBarElement.children).some(btn => btn.classList.contains('active'))) {
                tab.activate();
            }
        } else {
            this.secondaryTabBarElement.appendChild(tab.buttonElement);
            this.secondaryContentDiv.appendChild(tab.contentElement);
            if (!Array.from(this.secondaryTabBarElement.children).some(btn => btn.classList.contains('active'))) {
                tab.activate();
            }
        }
    }

    static deactivateTabsInBar(tabBar) {
        this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
            if(tab.buttonElement.parentElement === tabBar) {
                tab.deactivate();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Things I've already tried:

- Verified that there are no other event listeners on parent or ancestor elements that might be interfering with the drag-and-drop process.
- Checked for CSS styling issues to make sure neither of the tab bars or their tabs overlap with each other.
- Ensured that the secondaryTabBar is correctly initialized with the handleDrop event listener.
- Used console.log extensively to track the flow of events. I confirmed that the dragstart event is firing from secondaryTabBar tabs and that the dragover and drop events are being triggered on the intended targets.
- Inspected the event object during a drop event to see what the target and currentTarget properties are. This helped identify if some other element might be interfering.
- Used the browser's developer tools to inspect elements and verify there's no unexpected styling or structure issues.
- Ensured that the tabs and tab bars have the appropriate z-index in case there might be overlapping issues.

  Despite all of these checks, I'm still facing the issue.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this or how to fix it.

Thank you!